# Test massive website

Tags: testing, web, automated-tests

My company has just migrated all the code for our website to 3 identical servers on an off-site location. Now it is our job to test them.

However, the amount of websites/functionality that we have to test is exorbitant, and multiply that times 3! To check every single link and every single function is a daunting task. We are in the process of manually doing that right now.

My question to you guys/girls is this... Is there a way to automate the testing so we don't have to waste our time clicking, waiting, and checking the response, times 3?  ;-)

Let me know if you need any other info. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of functionality does the site have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to test functionality as it's exposed in the browser, then [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a good choice.  It lets you write automated tests in the context of the browser.  One nice feature for people who aren't as proficient at writing code is the ability to record actions taken in a browser and then replay them.

More likely, though, you need to consider your testing strategy from a holistic point of view.  You should consider how you can use unit testing to reduce the amount of manual link clicking or selenium testing you need to do.

Creating your automation suite will take some time, but having it ready to go the next time you move your site over to 6, 12, or 24 servers will prove invaluable.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I am reading the documentation now and it looks like it is what we need!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at tools for automating the browser. Watir is a very good solution. But there are other solutions, depending on your preferred development language.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want a link checker. There are a large number of software packages that will do this. Take a look at this list: http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html#LINK

Answer (score 0):

It might take just as long to automate the testing if you're only going to test just once.

However, if you're looking for a way to set up regression testing, I would take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is your best bet, but if your website has a lot of non-HTML stuff that you want to test you might wanna have a look at Sikuli: http://sikuli.org/